# Java getComponentCount fails to return correct value, (always zero )

Tags: swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I have A Jpanel with A GridLayout inside. Now I added  another Jpanel inside of there which draws a circle with PaintComponent. I'm now trying to get the ComponentCount() of the panel but it fails :s this is my code for mouse tracking :

```
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        int click_x = me.getX();
        int click_y = me.getY();
        int col = click_x/100;
        int row = click_y/100;
        System.out.println("select_C:"+col+" select_Y:"+row);



        System.out.println("COMPONENT COUNT:"+positionPanels[col][row].getComponentCount());

    }
```

it's okay, but when I click a container ( JPANEL with gridlayout(1,1) ) that actually contains another component (JPANEL) it returns ZERO as components count. please see screenshot for further details,...

[image]

clicking the red circle returned zero ... see System.out outputs... on screenshot, hope you guys can help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A red circle painted in a JPanel is not a component. You would have to add a JLabel (with a red circle as icon, for example) to the JPanel to have it contain a component.

If you actually added some component to the JPanel, then it probably means that the positionPanel is the inner component and not the containing component. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Are you sure? I am using paintComponent on a Jpanel ... do you suggest I use JLabel instead? (because its a component ... ) , also It's obligatory I use swing .. n

Comment: A JPanel is definitely a component. I was under the impression that you expected getComponentCount to return 1 because you painted a circle on this panel. If it's not the case, show us your code. We can't debug code we don't even see.

Comment: yes I was indeed expecting it to return 1 but it keeps returning 0 ... which code portion do you need ?

Comment: The one which initializes and fills the positionPanels array, and then adds a JPanel inside each of its elements.